# Obtain x as result for Re[x] in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to obtain the real part of the result of an operation which involves an undefined variable (let's say `x`).

How can I have Mathematica return `x` when I execute `Re[x]` if I know that `x` will never be a complex number? I think this involves telling Mathematica that `x` is a real, but I don't know how.

In my case the expression for which I want the real part is more complicated than a simple variable, but the concept will remain the same.

Some examples:

```
INPUT              OUTPUT         DESIRED RESULT
-----              ------         --------------
Re[x]              Re[x]          x
Re[1]              1              1
Re[Sin[x]]         Re[Sin[x]]     Sin[x]
Re[1+x+I]          1 + Re[x]      1+x
Re[1 + x*I]        1-Im[x]        1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use for example the input `Simplify[Re[x], x \[Element] Reals]` which will give `x` as output.

Answer (score 13):

Use  [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexExpand.html). It assumes that the variables are real unless you indicate otherwise. For example:

```
In[76]:= ComplexExpand[Re[x]]
Out[76]= x

In[77]:= ComplexExpand[Re[Sin[x]]]
Out[77]= Sin[x]

In[78]:= ComplexExpand[Re[1+x+I]]
Out[78]= 1+x
```

Comment: And if you want to save typing ComplexExpand all the time you could do $Post=ComplexExpand; first and then {Re[x], Re[Sin[x]], Re[1+x+I],Re[1+x*I]} evaluates to {x, Sin[x], 1 + x, 1}

Comment: @Rolf True and handy here, I agree. Although generally, I try to avoid using `$Pre` or `$Post` since it is easy to forget about them, and you start getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 5):

Two more possibilities:

```
Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, Refine[Re[x]]]

Refine[Re[x], x \[Element] Reals]
```

Both return `x`.

Answer (score 1):

It can at times be useful to define `UpValues` for a symbol.  This is far from robust, but it nevertheless can handle a number of cases.

```
Re[x] ^= x;
Im[x] ^= 0;

Re[x]
Re[1]
Re[1 + x + I] 
Re[1 + x*I]
```

> x
>
> 1
>
> 1 + x
>
> 1

`Re[Sin[x]]` does not evaluate as you desire, but one of the transformations used by `FullSimplify` does place it in a form that triggers `Re[x]`:

```
Re[Sin[x]] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> Sin[x]
> ```